# meteorhacks:aggregate to group mongo documents

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor server code tries to count all the records which are 4 months and newer with property `size:'4', color:'white'` but account all entires from any one user as one count, so no mater how many documents have been entered by the same user, the are all counted as one. but I am getting nothing in return. any ideas? thx

```js
      let date = new Date();
      date.setMonth(date.getMonth() - 4);
      let doc = UsageCol.aggregate([{
        $match: {
          createdAt: {
            $gte: date,
            $lte: new Date()
          },
          action: 'failBroadcast',
          plate: plate
        }
      }, {
        $group: {
          _id: {
            userId: "$userId"
          },
          count: {
            $sum: 1
          }
        }
      }]);
      for (var i = 0; i < doc.length; i++) {
        var obj = doc[i];
        console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
      }
```

Comment: What is plate variable value ? Make sure that is correct. And try removing date filter to confirm it's not the issue.

Comment: plate has a value fine, it is alphanumeric string. removing the date filter make it work, so there is a problem with the date filter. any ideas?

Comment: There is a offset between your local datetime  and UTC date time( datertime  values on server). new Date gives you date time  in your local time zone. So your comparing local date time values against UTC date time  values. The solution would be to create values in UTC before comparing using Date.UTC method .

Comment: @Veeram Could you please show the solution in code.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct function in JS to create date in UTC. So the only way I know is to pass the date variables to a Date.UTC function. Something like `var date = new Date(Date.UTC(2017, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0));`. You can create date in UTC pretty easily if you use moment js library.

Comment: @Veeram I just installed the moment.js in this Meteor code, how can it be done with moment? thx

Comment: You can try `var date = moment().utc().toDate();` to get current date time in UTC and to subtract 4 month you can try `var 4date = moment().utc().subtract(4, 'months').toDate();` More information here https://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: @Veeram the collection `createdAt` property has the epoch time which was created using `Date.now()` in javascript. So it is still not giving results using your last suggestion. Any ideas?

Comment: oh is your createdAt has a long type values ?

Comment: `Date.now()` is a number, not a date. Therefore, you should compare it to a number (use `getTime()` on your dates).

Comment: Thanks @MasterAM. I didn't know OP has saved the values using Date.now() function. Add getTime() on the dates.

Comment: This is not working: `      let dateTo = new Date().getTime();
      let dateFrom = new Date();
      dateFrom.setMonth(dateFrom.getMonth() - 4).getTime();` What is the correct syntax? thx

Comment: @Veeram Could you please give exact syntax? thx

Comment: `let dateTo = moment().utc().getTime();
      let dateFrom = moment().utc().subtract(4, 'months').getTime();` is not cutting it. moment(...).utc(...).getTime is not a function

Comment: `let dateTo = moment().utc().toDate().getTime();       let dateFrom = moment().utc().subtract(4, 'months').toDate().getTime();` using moment js

Comment: @Veeram Thank you. It works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I just wanted to clear some things up from this morning.

The only reason I recommended moment js was thinking we are storing the date in date type and there is no easy way to dynamically create date in UTC using java script date function

So now that we know you used `Date.now()` to save the dates, you don't need any moment js.

The correct syntax is

```
let dateToMillis = Date.now(); //The current millis from epoch.
let dateFrom = new Date(dateToMillis); // Use the current millis from epoch.
let dateFromMillis = dateFrom.setMonth(dateFrom.getMonth() - 4); // The millis 4 months ago from epoch.
```

Pass `dateToMillis` and `dateFromMillis` to aggregation query.

Comment: The second line, arg to Date should be dateToMillis?